# how to print Wordpress Woocommerce smart compare plugin as pdf

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, compare

I'm using smart compare woocommerce right now and I have tried using html to pdf plugins but they don't display all content like the images, button, categories etc. only some of the texts;
So I tried using dompdf plugin and print the index.php file inside the plugin but it's just printing out nothing.

here is what i put inside the index.php

```
$file = "index.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html_file($file);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

I have also tried creating a download pdf button 
    $wooscp = new WooSCP();  // assigned the object that smart compare plugin is using.
    Download

```
if (isset($_GET["compare-pdf"])) {


$html =  $wooscp->wooscp_load_compare_table(); //load the function that displays comparison results.

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
}
```

Do you guys know a solution for this or any plugin that would work?
Thank you.